# Maximum and minimum word extracted from a string

Tags: ruby

I do have an string as *`"Frederik will not come office tomorrow.So please you have to do his tasks".`* I want smallest and maximum length words as a hash as below:

```
{2=>["So", "to", "do"], 8=>["Frederik", "tomorrow"]}
```

So what would be shortest approach to do that?

Comment: I think the output you miss pasted,so I corrected. Please check and confirm. :)

Comment: @RubyLovely With respect to the `Edit` done to the post, you're not supposed correct Code posted by the OP. Edits shouldn't modify code even if/when the code is wrong.

Comment: @fmendez Yes,you are correct! I just told OP to confirm,as his words seems to me like that.

Comment: @RubyLovely Yes your edit is correct. Apologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 8):

Try the below:

```
w = "Frederik will not come office tomorrow.So please you have to do his tasks" 
p Hash[w.scan(/\w+/).group_by(&:length).minmax]

#=>{2=>["So", "to", "do"], 8=>["Frederik", "tomorrow"]}
```

Comment: @fguillen thanks for the edit. And to make my code more beautiful.

Comment: you were who made it brilliant, I just polished it a bit :P

Comment: @fguillen I also learned it from you. I didn't think about the `minmax` without block. :) I rethink after your edit. :)